# Своя подсветка цветов PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, color

[image: подсветку цветов]

Родная подсветка цветов занимает место и неудобна. 
Какой плагин отвечает? Хочу заменить на другой плагин с подсветкой конкретного значения.